# Developing ASP.NET Facebook App Locally

Tags: asp.net, facebook, graph, hosts

I've searched around and found a lot of advice saying to modify the hosts file as such:

```
127.0.0.1    mydomainname.com
```

I've done that, but my actual site at mydomainname.com is still being used. Any other troubleshooting steps I could take? Any other suggestions?

Comment: What kind of app is it? Connect? FBML Canvas? IFrame Canvas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply setup your canvas address as localhost. Unless you're using FBML, it works. See http://fbgraph.computerbeacon.net/tutorial/section1/createnewapp.aspx for an example.

Answer (score 1):

Restart your browser, try `ipconfig /flushdns` (I'm a bit hazy on Windows DNS caching so that may or may not help here) or restart your computer. Unless you've done something really weird, the hosts file should have priority, so something must be caching the DNS result.

Comment: Thank you, but I figured out the problem is that I had a virtual application in IIS and I wasn't serving out of inetpub, but does that mean I'm stuck serving only this website locally (as in my other local projects can't be served now?)

Comment: @Eric: Which version of IIS are you using? You should be able to bind any application to any host name in the newer versions.

Comment: IIS 7. I guess I just haven't ever done that, but I'm glad to know I can. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Just make your redirect_uri your localhost address like:

https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id={consumerKey}&redirect_uri=http://localhost:4403/Handshake

I have mine set up in visual studio to switch between localhost and live return_url's depending on whether debug or release is selected